# What regex will match this?

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression to match the following:

```
CONTEXT_84 =
```

or

```
CONTEXT_5 =
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
CONTEXT_\d{1,2} =
```

Which means:

> ```
> CONTEXT_\d{1,2}
> ```
>
> Match the characters “`CONTEXT_`” literally «`CONTEXT_`»
>      Match a single digit `0..9` «`\d{1,2}`»
>         Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «`{1,2}`»
>
> Created with RegexBuddy

Comment: +1 (assuming this is what the OP intended). Also RegexBuddy attempts to make a human readable explanation of the regex? That's kind of neat, I'll have to look at it.

Comment: Yeah - the explanation is exported from the "Create" Window of RegexBuddy - I found it very helpful when I was learning regex

Answer (score 7):

```
CONTEXT_(84|5) =
```

Comment: This is perfectly correct given the question, but probably not what the OP actually intended

Comment: I think you mean CONTEXT_(84|5).  You're match will match CONTEXT_8, CONTEXT_4, CONTEXT_5 and CONTEXT_|, but not CONTEXT_84.  Also, there should be a space or \s* or something before the '='

Comment: -1, wrong regex for the problem, as stated by another comment.

Answer (score 3):

it depends on your target language, but the main difference between the two is the numbers, so you can do this to get 'CONTEXT_' with at least one number followed by a space and an '=':

```
CONTEXT_[0-9]+ =
```

or this, to get 'CONTEXT_' with min of one, max of two numbers, followed by a space and an '=':

```
CONTEXT_[0-9]{1,2} =
```

Comment: While I can understand the last remark, I think you should at least point out that it matches everything - lest it be mistaken for a serious suggestion.

Comment: @Draemon, good point, well taken. I have edited the post to remove the flip answer.

Comment: Your last example is missing the =

Answer (score 1):

CONTEXT_[0-9]+ = *

Answer (score 1):

Your question already contains the answer: you ask

> how do I match `CONTEXT_84 =` **or** `CONTEXT_5 =`?

That's already all you need, the only thing missing is how to say **or** in Regexp, and that's `|`.

So, your solution is

```
CONTEXT_84 =|CONTEXT_5 =
```

You can shorten that by pulling out the common parts:

```
CONTEXT_(84|5) =
```

And you're done!

Answer (score 0):

```
CONTEXT_[\d]+ =
```

Comment: No need for the character class (the []) when matching \d.